# Overriding MenuItem ControlTemplate breaks click events

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'd like to override the MenuItem ControlTemplate so that I can customize the mouseover background color of my MenuItems.

I'm using the following xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#26222b"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Border Padding="10 0 10 0" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"  
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                          ContentSource="Header"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2f2a36"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

This does what I expect it to in terms of style, but the buttons no longer respond to click events.

I've also tried using a ControlTemplate.Trigger instead of a Style.Trigger to make the change I want. I don't know which solution is considered proper (please let me know) but neither seemed to address the problem at hand.

It's my understanding that I should be able to override the element's style without having to rewrite its click response functionality, so I assume I'm doing something wrong here to break it.

Just in case it's helpful, below is the xaml in which I've defined the menu itself:

```
        <Menu Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          IsMainMenu="True">
        <Menu.Items>
            <MenuItem Header="_File" DataContext="{Binding File}">
                <MenuItem Header="_New" Command="{Binding NewCommand}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Open" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save as..." Command="{Binding SaveAsCommand}"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Format" DataContext="{Binding Editor}">
                <MenuItem Header="_Format" Command="{Binding FormatCommand}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Word wrap" Command="{Binding WrapCommand}"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help" DataContext="{Binding Help}">
                <MenuItem Header="_About" Command="{Binding HelpCommand}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu.Items>
    </Menu>
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates for more info. MenuItem template has to be implemented correctly

Comment: Am I to understand from reading this that I'll need to override all these listed control templates just to make this change?

Comment: Perhaps not. But as you are modifying the template, then you need to follow the original template to a certain point. In your case you have a ContentPresenter for the Header, but where should rest of the MenuItem's appear ? In the documentation they use the PopUp Control for that.

Comment: Thank you very much, implementing the popup control was indeed the missing step. Will accept if you write that up as the answer.